# Distance between a Poisson and Normal distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_a$ be a random variable Poisson distributed with intensity  $a$.
That is 
$$\mathbb{P}(X_a=k)= e^{-a} a^k / (k!)$$
for any $k\in \mathbb{N}$.
Let 
$$Y_a=(X-a)/\sqrt{a}$$
the normalization of $X_a$ such that it has mean $0$ and variance $1$.
Let $F_{Y_a}$ its cumulative distribution function. That is
$$F_{Y_a}(t)=\mathbb{P}(Y_a\leq t).$$
Let $N$ be the standard normal distribution and $F_N$ its cumulative distribution function. That is
$$F_N(t)=\mathbb{P}(N\leq t) = \int_{-\infty}^t \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12 t^2} \mathrm{d}t.$$
Wikipedia says

> For sufficiently large values of $a$, (say $a$>1000), the normal distribution with mean $a$ and variance $a$ (standard deviation $\sqrt{a}$) is an excellent approximation to the Poisson distribution.

My question is:
 **How strong is the convergence of $Y_a$ against $N$ when $a\to\infty$?**

Do we only have *convergence in distribution* : $F_{Y_a}(t) \to N(t)$ when $a\to\infty$ for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Or can we say more?
In particular I would like to have an upper bound (depending on $a$) for
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |F_{Y_a}(t)-F_N(t)| \mathrm{d}t.$$
I would be even more happy if someone comes up with an upper bound for
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |F_{Y_a}(t)-F_N(t)|^p \mathrm{d}t \quad \text{with }p>1.$$
What is a good reference for this kind of results?

Comment: Possibly related? The Berry-Esseen Theoem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry–Esseen_theorem

Comment: Thanks GEdgar. I did not know about it. This is the kind of results I am looking for.

Comment: For $p=1$, see [L1 bounds in normal approximation](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1189000931) by Larry Goldstein, and the references therein.